# ROS Answers SE migration: error in gscam

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing gscam when i run `rosrun gscam gscam`  it shows error as:-

```
[FATAL] [1434739963.570463587]: Failed to PAUSE stream, check your gstreamer configuration.
[FATAL] [1434739963.570507671]: Failed to initialize gscam stream!
```

and when i run `roslaunch gscam v4l.launch` it shows like :

```
[FATAL] [1434739959.486995125]: Both GSCAM_CONFIG environment variable and 'gscam_config' rosparam are set. Please only define one.
[FATAL] [1434739959.487146853]: Failed to configure gscam!
```

even bin folder is not getting created as shown in [gscam wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam)

please help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211757/error-in-gscam/) by [Prashant Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22864/prashant-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-06-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To `rosrun gscam gscam`, change your GSCAM_CONFIG by: (you got error because /dev/video2 does not exist)

```
export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace"
```

To `roslaunch gscam v4l.launch` , modify your v4l.launch to: (you got error because gscam_config was set again in v4l.launch)

```
<launch>
  <!-- This launchfile should bring up a node that broadcasts a ros image
       transport on /webcam/image_raw -->

  <arg name="DEVICE" default="/dev/video0"/>
  <!-- The GStreamer framerate needs to be an integral fraction -->
  <arg name="FPS" default="30/1"/>
  <arg name="PUBLISH_FRAME" default="false"/>

  <node ns="v4l" name="gscam_driver_v4l" pkg="gscam" type="gscam" output="screen">
    <param name="camera_name" value="default"/>
    <param name="camera_info_url" value="package://gscam/examples/uncalibrated_parameters.ini"/>
    <!--<param name="gscam_config" value="v4l2src device=$(arg DEVICE) ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=$(arg FPS) ! ffmpegcolorspace"/>-->
    <param name="frame_id" value="/v4l_frame"/>
    <param name="sync_sink" value="true"/>
  </node>

  <node if="$(arg PUBLISH_FRAME)" name="v4l_transform" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="1 2 3 0 -3.141 0 /world /v4l_frame 10"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prashant Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22864/prashant-kumar/) on 2015-06-20**:
while trying to modify v4l.launch.  it says that I don't have permission to change that file.
any ideas?

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-06-20**:
Weird. Anyway, open a new terminal, do not `export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace"`, only launch v4l.launch. The point is you cannot set GSCAM_CONFIG twice.